# MongoDB backup after schema was changed

Tags: mongodb

I have created dump for foo collection, after that I have changed foo schema (added additional documents and fields), so is it possible in MongoDB to restore old data and keep current schema? Please suggest me some solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by keep current schema? There is no fixed schema in MongoDB so if you restore data from a dump it won't inherit any new fields written in a document. That said you can definitely restore your old data into a collection with a new schema and they can live side by side. See the following for a MongoDB data modeling overview: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#data-modeling-considerations-for-mongodb-applications

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not enforce a schema. You can easily restore your old documents into the same collection as your new ones. You can write your application to expect old-style or new-style documents when you query them. Or you could use `update` with operators like `set` or `rename` to update the old-style documents and make them conform to the new schema.